# How to make a PyQt application that only pops up a menu immediately?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like my application to consist only of a pop-up menu that opens immediately as soon as it is run. I attempted this solution but nothing appears when I run it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QPoint)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMenu, QAction)

def clicked():
    print("CLICKED")

if __name__ == '__main__':       
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    menu = QMenu()
    menu.addAction(QAction("&Click me", triggered=clicked))
    menu.exec_(QCursor().pos())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will display a simple popup window with a single option, that calls the `clicked` function on click:

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QCursor
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMenu


def clicked():
    print("CLICKED")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    menu = QMenu()
    menu.addAction("Click me", clicked)
    menu.exec_(QCursor().pos())
```

Or if you want to use `QAction` still, then move its definition outside:

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QCursor
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMenu, QAction


def clicked():
    print("CLICKED")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    menu = QMenu()
    action = QAction("&Click me", triggered=clicked)
    menu.addAction(action)
    menu.exec_(QCursor().pos())
```

As pointed out by [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) in the comment below:

> Qt does not take ownership of actions added via addAction. You must
>   keep an explicit reference to them, otherwise they will get
>   garbage-collected.

Note I am using `PySide2`, but it shouldn't change anything.

Comment: Yes you can simply replace PySide2 with PyQt5 and his code works just fine well except for the fact that `QApplication()` needs to be `QApplication([])`

Comment: Qt does not take ownership of actions added via `addAction`. You must keep an explicit reference to them, otherwise they will probably get garbage-collected immediately. In the OP's example, a menu **is** displayed, but since it has no items, it will only be a few pixels wide/high.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks @ekhumoro! I have added your explanation into the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am not certain how minimalistic you want this Menu to be but this is a more static menu (aka it sticks around) with more than one option in case you are trying to build some kind of Menu driven Windowing platform or just a Menu of commands.  Also it being a class allows it to be importable to whatever you might be developing large scale.  Further you can expand the menu by adding additional menu items with different actions and lastly it follows basic pyqt programming methodologies

```
from sys import exit as sysExit

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QAction, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QMenuBar

class MainMenu(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setMaximumSize(self.minimumSize())

        self.Click1Act = QAction("&Click Me 1", triggered=self.Clicked1)
        self.Click2Act = QAction("&Click Me 2", triggered=self.Clicked2)

        self.SimpleMenu = QMenuBar()
        self.ClickMenu  = self.SimpleMenu.addMenu('Clickables')
        self.ClickMenu.addAction(self.Click1Act)
        self.ClickMenu.addSeparator()
        self.ClickMenu.addAction(self.Click2Act)

        HBox = QHBoxLayout()
        HBox.addWidget(self.SimpleMenu)

        self.setLayout(HBox)

    def Clicked1(self):
        print("CLICKED ONE")

    def Clicked2(self):
        print("CLICKED TWO")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainThred = QApplication([])

    MainGui = MainMenu()
    MainGui.show()

    sysExit(MainThred.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you, Dennis! This is a regular QMenuBar which stays around and needs an explicit click for activation. It works but it's not what I need.